# sysread overhead for Perl in Linux

Tags: linux, perl

I have a network daemon which receives messages of a fixed length (44 Bytes) on a TCP socket.

I am trying to determine what the best length in bytes I should be reading with sysread is. I can of course do a loop that does a sysread for 44 bytes, but I'd like to come up with an optimal size.

I can see an advantage to not having say, a megabyte worth of data to do substr on, but I can also see why doing a thousand sysread calls can cause slowness.

Is there a good size recommendation for doing sysreads over the public internet?

Edit:
The script gets a bunch of the 44 byte messages, they are queued up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The larger the better! `sysread` will return as soon any bytes are available.

Since you're never guaranteed to get a whole message and since you're never guaranteed to not have more than one message, you need to have a loop on the Perl side. Since you already have a loop on the Perl side, so you might as well get as much data as possible from the system in one go to avoid needless system calls.

```
use constant READ_SIZE => 65*1024;

my $buf = '';
while (1) {
   my $rv = sysread($fh, $buf, READ_SIZE, length($buf));
   die if !defined($rv);
   last if !$rv;

   while ($buf =~ s/^(.{44})//s) {
      my $msg = $1;
      process_msg($msg);
   }
}
```

Pick a size and monitor `$buf`'s size. If it often approaches `READ_SIZE`, increase `READ_SIZE`.

Comment: After doing some benchmarking, it seems like this is the correct answer in my application.

Comment: @GoldenNewby, Of course, letting Perl do that buffering itself (i.e using `read` with length 44 instead of `sysread`) would probably be even faster! I just blindly accepted your premise that `sysread` was going to be used.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=435814, in that discussion, they say: "Read cannot do that except at the end of file". In the context of reading from a TCP socket, what does that mean exactly? I am okay with getting back a partial result, but I'm not okay with having to wait around while it attempts to get a certain number of bytes. Is it possible to do a non-blocking read?

Comment: @GoldenNewby, But you said you're using TCP. I already said what `read` does with TCP.

Comment: Is the idiom of reading subsequent sysreads into the same scalar and removing frames via regexp efficient?  The general wisdom in programming is to not build strings by appending.  And does the regexp-prefix-trimming copy the string or does it edit it in-place in memory?

Comment: @user2243865, Re "The general wisdom in programming is to not build strings by appending", Say what? Kinda hard to append a string to another without appending it.

Comment: @user2243865, Re "And does the regexp-prefix-trimming copy the string or does it edit it in-place in memory?", In this case, it will add a start-of-string offset to the scalar.

Comment: @ikegami, I meant that if you had a series of strings, and you needed to append them all together, it would be more efficient to collect them all in an array first and `join()` them instead of doing `while(...) { $accumulator .= $part ;}` or whatever.  But this is different b/c the string needs to be processed as it's arriving, which is why I ask.  But thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user2243865, 1) I don't have a series of strings. 2) That assumes the memory is periodically freed, but `$buf` will exist for the entire span of the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the overhead is and only you can measure if one is faster than the other, but if I were to try a size out of the clear blue sky, I would go with `4092` bytes first. That gives you up to 93 messages to process and it is under the magic 4Kb size, which sounds like a good place to start.

You can find out the [page size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29#Unix_and_POSIX-based_operating_systems) on the system the program is running, and tune accordingly. I would start with `int(PAGE_SIZE / MESSAGE_SIZE)` and see if that performs better than one `sysread` for each message.

On the other hand, [`perl` uses 8KB buffers by default](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/dc281e6088d189558b79a5121119b7196c8b3db0:/perlio.h#l192):

```
 192 /* The default buffer size for the perlio buffering layer */
 193 #ifndef PERLIOBUF_DEFAULT_BUFSIZ
 194 #define PERLIOBUF_DEFAULT_BUFSIZ (BUFSIZ > 8192 ? BUFSIZ : 8192)
 195 #endif
```

You might also find the [discussion that led to the change](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2010/11/msg165785.html) informative.

Comment: I believe a lot of systems in use still have 4KB virtual memory page size.

Comment: The 4KB/8KB buffer does not apply to `sysread`, only buffered reads. `sysread` will result in `read`(2) of exactly the specified size.

Comment: @ikegami I understand that, but the reasoning that led to increasing the buffer size in `perl` might be informative (and might suggest that 4KB is too small).

Answer (score 0):

The system call won't copy bytes that aren't transmitted.  If you have a 44 byte message perl will return a 44 byte string always.  The size you provide is merely a maximum, used to size the buffer provided to the kernel.  The value to providing more than 44 bytes is that if there is more than one message queued, you will get them all in a single system call.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading post, in this situation there are a bunch of queued up 44 byte messages. There can be hundreds of them.